# centos 6, switching between different languages

Tags: centos, language

I installed CentOS 6.3 US English as default. Since my PC has japanese keyboard I changed 
default keyboard layout to be Japanese (System->Preferences->keyboard menu).
Then I learned I needed to install japanese language support:
$ yum install "@Japanese support".
Now, I need to occasionally enter japanese texts, but
keep my OS menus etc. in English. What should I additionally do 
to be able to enter japanese texts, say in Google Chrome search text box?

Answer (score 1):

I was too quick to ask. Anyway I found how to configure settings.
http://blog.goo.ne.jp/rm_-rf/e/bbfb60fdc85c445ebb497892427eba58

In English:

1. From System -> Preference -> **** menu
2. Tick "Enable input method feature". Select "Use IBus (recommended)".
3. Click "Input method preferences"
4. On "Input Method" tab select japanese->Anthy, and click Add.
5. If necessary, change your shortcut key on General tab

That's all.